# About a representation of D4

Tags: representation-theory

Could you please give ma an example of a linear representation of the dihedral group D4? all references give this matrix representation.

[image]

How could I express it linearly?

Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean to «express it linearly»?

Comment: I want to define this representation by identifying S0 and S1 as linear transformations, then we will have linear rep. which corresponds the given matrix rep.

Comment: $S_0$ and $S_1$ are mapped to the linear maps $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ whose matrices with respecto to the usual basis are precisely the matrices you wrote. In a way, there is nothing to be done to get a linear representation from a matrix representation,